# Get Visitors location (IP) without use of 3rd party lib

Tags: javascript

I am creating a `Javascript` for my users and i am trying to make it as light weight as possible.

Because of this i am not using any outside liberay (not even `JQuery`) if possible i want to keep it that way.

So my question is: Is it possible to get a visitors `IP` address without the use of External calls or lib.

By external calls i am refering to:

`Ajax`, `google Jsapi`, and others

Note that i have been looking at the answer to this question [get client ip using just javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript)
However this is not what i am looking as it goes outside of the current page to collect its information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This information is not provided by the browser to the scripts running inside web pages, so there is no way to access it without interogating a remote server (external call).

Comment: Okay.. what would you suggest to be the most light weight solution?

Comment: Just try $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] in PHP

Comment: I think this answer is pretty lightweight (because you don't need to set up the server), but you will have to turn the code to pure JS if you don't want to use JQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17808050/1669279

Anyway, there are quite a few similar questions on stackoverflow and you might find a better suited answer there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest java

```
function myIP()
{ 
    var yip2=java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();   
    var yip=yip2.getHostAddress();
    return yip;
}
```

Comment: is this the host or the client?

Comment: and isnt this Java and not javascript?

Comment: This is a server side solution.